# Can I control frequency of AWS S3 bucket access log delivery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, log-files, amazon-s3

I have enabled access logging for an AWS S3 bucket. Now I get log files delivered to my chosen destination. Each file has a name of the form YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss-guidguidguid with the time representing the last entry in the log file. Each file contains one or more lines. Each line represents one access.

I am getting a lot of tiny log files. Most files contain just one line, some as many as five. I am accessing the bucket up to a few dozen times a minute, so I'm getting 3-20 new log files per minute.

I have found mention online that these logs are normally delivered hourly. Have I overlooked an option somewhere that controls the delivery frequency or possibly thresholds that trigger delivery?

Comment: 20-30 log files per minute?  That doesn't sound normal, but you didn't per chance configure the bucket to save its logs in itself, did you? Because saving the log creates a log entry... You'll want to log into a different bucket.

Comment: Yeah, it's crazy. I'll make 50 requests in a minute, and get a dozen log files, each one with just 1-3 requests in it. 2016-12-08-13-01-27-xxxx contains 3 lines, 2016-12-08-13-01-35-xxxx contains the next line, 2016-12-08-13-01-38-xxxx contains two more lines, etc

Comment: Which region is the bucket in?  I haven't needed my S3 logs lately so I haven't kept a close eye on the actual process -- so I don't have any recent observations... but I do have *years* of logs that I've been meaning to create a script to gather them up into tarballs with aggressive compression... so maybe I can spot a trend.  Of course, with some buckets taking millions of hits per day, I could have the same frequency of log files and it would not seem as unusual unusual... but I have some low traffic buckets, too. But... I don't think this is configurable.

Comment: I think that bucket is in us-west-1

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: ***no***.

Long answer (from [Logging requests with server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html#LogDeliveryBestEffort)

> ### Best-effort server log delivery
>
> Server access log records are delivered on a best-effort basis. Most
> requests for a bucket that is properly configured for logging result
> in a delivered log record. Most log records are delivered within a few
> hours of the time that they are recorded, but they can be delivered
> more frequently.
>
> The completeness and timeliness of server logging is not guaranteed.
> The log record for a particular request might be delivered long after
> the request was actually processed, or it might not be delivered at
> all. It is possible that you might even see a duplication of a log
> record. The purpose of server logs is to give you an idea of the
> nature of traffic against your bucket. Although log records are rarely
> lost or duplicated, be aware that server logging is not meant to be a
> complete accounting of all requests.

Which basically means that you have no control over when or how S3 drops the logs (other than the path prefix and whether they're named by event time or delivery time).

Your best chance of wrangling them in a timely manner is probably to use S3 Lambda triggers to clean them up "as you go", or possibly use a trigger to reshape them into JSON then dump them into a Kinesis Firehose and let it handle batching and parquet-ifying them so they're faster and cheaper to process with Athena or what have you.